# sql query two field from one table join one field from a table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
users(userid, username)
```

and

```
cases(cid,assign_to,received_by)
```

I want to join `assign_to` and
 `received_by` with `user_id` and produce
`username`.

How do I join these table and how I
 produce `username` to `assign_to` and
 `received_by`?

These two fields `assign_to` and
`received_by` are stored different
 `userid`.

```
> eg assign_to                      received_by
>      1                                   3
>      2                                   4
```

I want to produce `username` in these fields.

Comment: You've asked 11 questions and never accepted one answer?

Comment: It's bad style not to accept any answer. But that should not be a reason to vote down (or close) his question.

Answer (score 2):

```
select u1.* from Users as u1
join Cases as c1
on u1.userid = c1.received_by
join cases as c2
on u1.userid = c2.assign_to
```

Here is basic join for the purpose